# Combination of Block and With - Unexpected results

Tags: evaluation, scoping, hold

I'm trying to use `Block` to prevent a function from executing.  In this example, the function I'm trying to block will simply be `Plus`.  My code has an inner `With` clause inside the `Block`.  The `With` clause performs some operations itself, and also receives an expression passed-in as a function parameter.  In the below example, I emulate that with an outer `With` clause.

Unexpectedly, for a simple two-operand `Plus`, `Block` is only blocking `Plus` for the expression passed-in to the inner `With` clause, not the `Plus` operation hard-coded into the `With` clause.  For a three-operand `Plus`, it blocks everything.

A canonical code sample which produces this behavior is shown below.  Any ideas?  I may switch to using `Inactivate` for my real problem, though I have to think it through a bit more.  Thanks!

EDIT: Changed example to `Print` the results instead of `Hold`'ing them, as the `Hold[#]& @ ...` syntax required to illustrate the "extent of execution *within* the `Block`" was obfuscating my intent.

```
With[{a := 1 + 2},
 Block[{Plus}, SetAttributes[{Plus}, HoldAllComplete];
  With[{x := {a + 3 + 4, a*2*2}, y := {a + 3 + (4 + 5), a*2*2}},
   Print["x: ", x];
   Print["Unevaluated@x: ", Unevaluated@x];
   Print["y: ", y];
   Print["Unevaluated@y: ", Unevaluated@y];
   ]]]
```

Results:

```
x: {7+(1+2),12}
Unevaluated@x: {(1+2)+3+4,(1+2)*2*2}
y: {3+(1+2)+(4+5),12}
Unevaluated@y: {(1+2)+3+(4+5),(1+2)*2*2}
```

EDIT:

Expected results:

```
x: {(3+4)+(1+2),(1+2)*4} (* DELTA *)
Unevaluated@x: {(1+2)+3+4,(1+2)*2}
y: {3+(1+2)+(4+5),(1+2)*4} (* DELTA *)
Unevaluated@y: {(1+2)+3+(4+5),(1+2)*2}
```

My real code has to do with code injection into held expressions.

EDIT: Another simplified example (Thanks @PierreALBARÈDE):

```
Block[{Plus}, Attributes[Plus] = {HoldAllComplete}; 
 Print /@ {Plus[1, 2], Plus[1, 2, 3], Plus[1 + 2, 0], 
   Plus[1 + 2 + 3, 0]};]
```

Results:

```
3
6
1+2
1+2+3
```

It seems that only the `HoldAllComplete` attribute is doing anything...

Comment: Apparently you are not happy with the results.  Could you add a column of expected results to make the question more clear?

Comment: @PierreALBARÈDE : Added

Comment: Keep in mind that according to the docs `Plus` and `Times` have internal rules that are applied before the standard evaluation cycle. You cannot override them. It does not say what they are exactly, so they may or may not be the cause of the trouble.

Comment: Ahh @MichaelE2, that would be good news, maybe my test code just happened to hit one of those cases.  It's odd that using `Inactivate[expr,Plus]` instead of `Block[{Plus},expr]` behave differently, and that the two-operand vs three-operand versions of `Plus` behave differently, but like you say... it could be some oddity of the internal rules.

Comment: It seems that numeric arguments at level one are added.  So `Plus[Plus[1, 2], 3, 4]` evaluates to `Plus[Plus[1, 2], 7]` but the argument `Plus[1, 2]` is not evaluated because of `HoldAllComplete` (which does not stop the rule for adding level-one numbers).

Comment: Inactivating `Plus`, replaces the head `Plus` by `Inactive[Plus]`, so that `Plus[..]` is never evaluated and the internal rules are never applied.

Comment: @MichaelE2: Regarding "It seems that numeric arguments at level one are added." -- I agree, but do you consider this expected behavior?

Comment: It doesn't say what the internal rules are....I don't know what to expect.

Comment: Fair enough @MichaelE2!

Comment: When I see a question about the behavior of Plus, where someone is attempting to change it using `Unprotect` or `Block`, I always think "No. Don't do that. Find another way to get what you need." It's just not an approach that can be made to work reliably.

Comment: Glad to see another person agree that it's just an issue specific to `Plus` @DanielLichtblau !  Looks like I just picked a bad example function to use in my testing!

Answer (score 1):

You are running afoul of self-created complications when using the unnecessary `Hold[#]&@...` form, instead of `Hold@...` or `Hold[...]`:

```
With[
 {a := 1 + 2},
 Block[{Plus},
  SetAttributes[{Plus}, HoldAllComplete];
  With[
   {x := a + 3 + 4, y := a + 3 + (4 + 5)},
   Hold@{x, Unevaluated@x, Hold@x, y, Unevaluated@y, Hold@y}]
 ]
]

(* Out: 
Hold[{
  (1 + 2) + 3 + 4, 
  Unevaluated[(1 + 2) + 3 + 4], 
  Hold[(1 + 2) + 3 + 4], 
  (1 + 2) + 3 + (4 + 5), 
  Unevaluated[(1 + 2) + 3 + (4 + 5)],
  Hold[(1 + 2) + 3 + (4 + 5)]
}]
*)
```

Although I don't know what your ultimate goal is here, nevertheless this seems consistent.

Comment: Thanks @MarcoB.  I added some clarification on my use of `Hold[#]&@...` above.  My ultimate goal has to do with code injection into held expressions, so I actually want to let everything *except* the `Plus` (in this simple example) pre-execute before holding anything.

Comment: Perhaps I could have used a less-trivial (but less canonical) bit of sample code, but wouldn't you agree that the as-written `Hold` form should execute the `Hold` before leaving the `Block`, therefore producing my expected results of `Hold[(1+2)+(3+4)]` for the first output line?

Comment: I am not sure that I understand. `Hold` won't have any effects "after the fact": in other words, once an expression is evaluated, applying Hold to it won't do much anymore. Compare `Hold[(3 + 2)]` (returning `Hold[3 + 2]`) with `Hold[#] &@(3 + 2)` (returning `Hold[5]`). The latter `Hold` was "too late" and had no chance of affecting anything.

Comment: @Sean, if you need something to not evaluate before being passed to a pure function, you might want to add an appropriate attribute, e.g. `Function[Null, Hold[#], {HoldAll}] @ (3 + 2)`

Comment: @MarcoB: yes, but if `Hold` is applied prior to exiting the `Block` (where `Plus` is inert still), we aren't "after the fact", no?

Comment: Replace the outer `Hold[#] &` by `Print`, the result is the same and the intention more clear.

Comment: @J.M.: thanks for the suggestion, my real function does have a `HoldAllComplete` attribute.  The code I'm injecting into a held expression, though, cannot be assumed to be a function, and I'd prefer not to wrap anything in "extra" functions.

Comment: Good idea @PierreALBARÈDE; I think the `Hold` is obfuscating my intent.

Comment: @Sean In your `Block`, `Plus` is not inert. See `Block[{Plus}, SetAttributes[{Plus}, HoldAllComplete]; Plus[3, 2]]` which returns 5. What do you mean then?

Comment: @MarcoB, I agree that the code you wrote in your last comment is expected to return 5, but the transformation from `Plus[3,2]` to `5` only happens *after* you leave the `Block`.

Comment: I updated the sample code to use `Print` instead of `Hold` (thanks for the suggestion @PierreALBARÈDE) -- I think this simplifies the discussion considerably.

Comment: Even simpler try this:  `Block[{Plus},
 Attributes[Plus] = {HoldAllComplete};
 Print /@ {Block[{Plus},
 Attributes[Plus] = {HoldAllComplete};
 Print /@ {Plus[1, 2], Plus[1 + 2, 3, 4], Plus[1 + 2, 3, 4, 5], Plus[1 + 2, 3, 4 + 5]};] Plus[1, 2],    Plus[1 + 2, 3, 4], Plus[1 + 2, 3, 4, 5], Plus[1 + 2, 3, 4 + 5]};]` Then you see that only the outermost `Plus` is evaluated.

Comment: OK the Block does nothing at all.  It is only the HoldAllComplete that is working.

Comment: I like the simple example @PierreALBARÈDE.  Here's my version: `Block[{Plus}, Attributes[Plus] = {HoldAllComplete}; Print /@ {Plus[1, 2], Plus[1, 2, 3], Plus[1 + 2, 0], Plus[1 + 2 + 3, 0]};]`. Results: `3, 6, 1+2, 1+2+3`.

Comment: So the answer is probably: you can't Block Plus.

Comment: That could very-well be true @PierreALBARÈDE.  That would be good, because my real problem has nothing to do with `Plus`, so if that is an isolated issue, then I am fine.  I wonder if there is an entire "class" of system functions that you can't `Block`-out, though.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/119174/discussion-between-pierre-albarede-and-sean).